# What can be unit tested in this Java method involving pagination of data?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, pagination, mockito

Beginner here at unit testing. Following is the method to be tested -

```
public ListBeneficiaryResponseDTO getBeneficiaryOfMerchants(Long merchantId, Integer page, Integer pageSize,
                                                       String sortDirection, String sortField) {
        LOGGER.info("Inside getBeneficiaryOfMerchants method");

        // default we are setting to added on desc sort
        Sort sort = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC,"addedOn");
        if(sortField != null && sortDirection != null) {
            sort = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.fromString(sortDirection),sortField);
        }

        Pageable pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page-1, pageSize, sort);
        Page<Beneficiary> pageOfBeneficiaries = beneficiaryRepository.findAllByMerchantId(merchantId, pageRequest);

        List<BeneficiaryResponseDTO> benResonseDtoList = new ArrayList<BeneficiaryResponseDTO>();

        for( Beneficiary ben: pageOfBeneficiaries.getContent()) {
            benResonseDtoList.add(this.getBeneficiaryResponseDTO(ben));
        }
        ListBeneficiaryResponseDTO formattedListBen = new ListBeneficiaryResponseDTO(pageOfBeneficiaries.getTotalPages(),pageOfBeneficiaries.getTotalElements(),pageOfBeneficiaries.getNumber(),benResonseDtoList);
        return formattedListBen;
    }
```

In order to write tests, I thought, what can this method do wrong, given the underlying method calls work fine.
Well, I am not sure, but may be some error in putting the elements into the list.

So, I thought writing a test to ensure that the expected number of elements are present in the list benResonseDtoList.

Following is what I tried -

```
@Test
public void testGetBeneficiariesOfMerchant() throws Exception {

    Long merchantId = 2l;
    List<Beneficiary> beneficiaryList = new ArrayList<Beneficiary>();
    beneficiaryList.add(getBeneficiaryDto());
    beneficiaryList.add(getBeneficiaryDto());


    Page<Beneficiary> beneficiaries = new PageImpl<Beneficiary>(beneficiaryList); //But I am not sure how many entries are there in the page created.
Mockito.when(beneficiaryRepository.findAllByMerchantId(any(),any())).thenReturn(beneficiaries);
KeyManager keyManager = Mockito.mock(KeyManager.class);


ListBeneficiaryResponseDTO list = beneficiaryService.getBeneficiaryOfMerchants(merchantId,1,2, "DESC","addedOn");
```

If there were a clear correlation between the number of elements in beneficiaryList and the entries in pageOfBeneficiaries, I could test that.

Comment: What does your getBeneficiaryDto() method returns?

Comment: *"In order to write tests, I thought, what can this method do wrong,"* --- This might be the wrong approach to finding test cases. UnitTests verify *desiredpublic observable behavior* so the better question is: *when I input this set of data, what is the expected return value (if any) and how should it communicate with its dependencies?*

Comment: @ThudaniHettimulla it returns a Beneficiary entity object.

Comment: In what world does all underlying methods work fine all the time? You should write your unit tests to handle "error" scenarios as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to know the testing scenarios for `getBeneficiaryOfMerchants()` function given underlining functions are working correctly.

For a given

> merchantId, page, pageSize, sortDirection, sortField

ListBeneficiaryResponseDTO would be fixed, let's call this ListBeneficiaryResponseDTO **expectedList** (you have to construct it as you already know the correct output)

**So you should be comparing the following:-**

**Actual Output:**

```
ListBeneficiaryResponseDTO actualList =  beneficiaryService.getBeneficiaryOfMerchants(merchantId,1,2, "DESC","addedOn");
```

**Expected Output:** 
ListBeneficiaryResponseDTO expectedList(already defined above)

Comparing both the outputs:-

1. Compare field by field **actualList** & **expectedList**
2. Override the Equals method of the ListBeneficiaryResponseDTO class(or you can use lombok.EqualsAndHashCode to avoid boilerplate code) and do the following:-
   `assertEquals(**actualList**, **expectedList**)`